# Python time in format => [days:hours:minutes:seconds] to seconds

Tags: python, datetime, time, dry, seconds

I have this function that tranforms for example

```
timeToSeconds("1:12:45:66.6")
>>>132366.6
```

But I admit it don't follow the DRY concept, check it out:

```
def timeToSeconds(time):
  t = time.split(':')
  try:
    if len(t) == 1:
      try:
        type(eval(t[0])) in [int, float]
      except:
        return False
      return eval(time)
    elif len(t) == 2:
      return float(t[-1]) + float(t[-2]) * 60
    elif len(t) == 3:
      return float(t[-1]) + float(t[-2]) * 60 + float(t[-3]) * 3600
    elif len(t) == 4:
      return float(t[-1]) + float(t[-2]) * 60 + float(t[-3]) * 3600 + float(t[-4]) * 86400
    else:
      return False
  except:
    return False
```

How would be a better way to write it? Note that is return False when input contains characters.

Comment: how the hell second is greater then 60???

Comment: is the input h:m:s:ms or d:h:m:s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return `False` to indicate an error. `False == 0.0` in Python. `0.0` is a valid result for `"0:0:0:0.0"`. You could allow exceptions to propagate instead:

```
def to_sec(timedelta_string, factors=(1, 60, 3600, 86400)):
    """[[[days:]hours:]minutes:]seconds -> seconds"""
    return sum(x*y for x, y in zip(map(float, timedelta_string.split(':')[::-1]), factors))
```

Or if you need to suppress exceptions then return `None`:

```
def timeToSeconds(time, default=None):
    try:
        return to_sec(time)
    except ValueError:
        return default
```

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira: I've updated the answer to support `[[[days:]hours:]minutes:]seconds` input

Comment: Better to use built-ins than manual arithmetic. also the code is not that readable if you write it in long single line.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: there is no need to downvote. The code is correct simple and more efficient than your solution. Using `timedelta` brings nothing here.

Answer (score 2):

This should work,

```
from datetime import timedelta

def timeToSeconds(s):
    try:
        rparts = reversed(map(float, s.split(':')))
        keys = ['seconds', 'minutes', 'hours', 'days']
        td = timedelta(**dict(zip(keys, rparts)))
        return td.total_seconds()
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

[Fiddle](http://ideone.com/iocHi8)

Comment: it is incorrect. Try the input from the question. You should return `td.total_seconds()` instead. Also, you don't need `reversed()`: `timedelta(**dict(zip("days:hours:minutes:seconds".split(":"), map(float, s.split(':'))))).total_seconds()`

Comment: it is not calculating days... timeToSeconds("1:0:0:0") => 
0

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira I missed the `total_seconds()`. Added that. now it works.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian reversed is necessary, otherwise `1:0` would return `86400` instead of `60`

Comment: you're right. I've made the same mistake in my answer (it is fixed now). You could also use `.split(":")[::-1]` to reverse the list. `timedelta` solution is slower than the sum-based one from my answer for some reason.

Comment: There is no need for `list()`.

Comment: @EOL reversed returns a iterator, so list is necessary. This could be eliminated by using s.split(':')[::-1] as J.F. Sebastian suggested.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira: `zip()` can take an iterator, so `list()` is indeed not needed. You can try it by yourself by running the code in the answer without `list()`: it does work.

Comment: @EOL agreed with you. `list` is not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

```
def timeToSeconds(time):
    multi = [1,60,3600,86400]
    try:
        time = map(float,time.split(":"))
        t_ret = 0
        for i,t in enumerate(reversed(time)):
            t_ret += multi[i] * t
        return t_ret
    except ValueError:
        return None

print timeToSeconds("1:12:45:66.6")
print timeToSeconds("12:45:66.6")
print timeToSeconds("45:66.6")
print timeToSeconds("66.6")
print timeToSeconds("c")
```

Output:

```
132366.6
45966.6
2766.6
66.6
None
```